# How to remove a tag from a javascript variable

Tags: jquery

How to remove some part of data from a variable

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/9yvk50go/

When once clicked on submit , i want to remove this part of text

```
'<p class="tcPriceWrap">25</p>'
```

So that i can have toppings array with only these values

```
Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML
Honey with Carmel  10 ML
```

The below is the HTML

```
<div class="prd-items-detials">    
<div style="display: block;" class="Topping-details" id="4">
   <section id="topping_tsection_4">
      <aside>
         <h6 class="tdHeading">Quantity      1</h6>
         <section class="secclass">
            <a data-id="4" topping_id="1" id="4_ZZ_0_ZZ_0" topp_name="Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML" top_price="25" class="tpActive">
               Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML 
               <p class="tcPriceWrap">25</p>
            </a>
         </section>
         <section class="secclass">
            <a data-id="4" topping_id="2" id="4_ZZ_0_ZZ_1" topp_name="Honey with Carmel  10 ML" top_price="25" class="tpActive">
               Honey with Carmel  10 ML 
               <p class="tcPriceWrap">25</p>
            </a>
         </section>
      </aside>
   </section>


</div>

    <input type="button" id="someid" value="Submit"/>

  </div>
```

This is my javascript

```
var toppings = [];

$(document).on("click", "#someid", function(e) {

$("#topping_tsection_4").find('.tdHeading').each(function () {
                values = [];
                $(this).parent().find('.tpActive').each(function () {

                    alert($(this).text().trim());
                    values.push($(this).text().trim());
                });
                if(values.length>0)
                {
                    toppings.push({
                        'name': $(this).text().trim(),
                        'value': values
                    });
                }
            });


    });    // close of save event listener
```

Comment: You want them both removed?

Comment: yes correct , i want to eliminate the p tag from both .

Comment: So why not just use `$('.tcPriceWrap').remove()`?

Comment: Do you only want them removed from the alert or do you want them removed from the DOM?

Comment: Thanks , i want to remove from the alert only and not from the DOM .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to keep that data in the DOM, I'll suggest this replacement in your code:

```
$(this).parent().find('.tpActive').each(function () {
  alert($(this).text().trim());
  values.push($(this).text().trim());
});
```

for this:

```
$(this).parent().find('.tpActive').each(function () {
  // Clone the element to prevent any change in the original DOM object.
  var $el = $(this).clone(); 
  // Remove what you want.
  $el.find('.tcPriceWrap').remove();

  alert($el.text().trim());

  values.push($el.text().trim());
});
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your `alert`.

```
alert($(this).clone().children().remove().end().text().trim());
```

It's basically

`.clone` cloning the object

`.children` getting the children of the cloned object

`.remove`  removing all the children of cloned object

`.end` going back to selection after that get the text

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want something like this:

```
$("#submitid").click(function(){
    $(".tcPriceWrap").each(function(){$(this).remove();});
});
```

[jsfiddleURL](http://jsfiddle.net/9yvk50go/5/)